# Programmatically hide iOS widgets?

Tags: ios, widget, ios-extensions

I have developed an iOS 14 desktop widget for an application and I would like to only make it available to some users.  Is there a way to disable widgets the first time your application runs so that you can hide it from some of your users?

Comment: did you find any way to achieve it?

Comment: I haven't found a way to hide them yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the supportedFamilies modifier on the WidgetConfiguration to [] then the widget no longer shows in the widget gallery. That might be an option.

```
public var body: some WidgetConfiguration {

IntentConfiguration(
  kind: kind,
  intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, 
  provider: Provider()
) { entry in
  widget_mainEntryView(entry: entry)
}
.configurationDisplayName("Widget")
.description("Widget")
.supportedFamilies([])
}
```